# Force plotly violin plot not to display a violin on zero values

Tags: r, plotly, violin-plot

I have measurements from several groups which I would like to plot as violin plots:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(val = c(runif(100,1,5),runif(100,1,5),rep(0,100)),
                 group = c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100),rep("C",100)))
```

Using `R`'s `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = group, y = val, color = group)) + geom_violin()
```

I get:
[image]

But when I try to get the equivalent with `R`'s `plotly` using:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = df$group, y = df$val, split = df$group, type = 'violin', box = list(visible = F), points = F, showlegend = T, color = df$group)
```

I get:
[image]

Where group "C" gets an inflated/artificial violin.

Any idea how to deal with this and not by using `ggplotly`?

Comment: Interestingly if you simply use ggplotly on the plot you initially created, it works just fine. Don't posting that as an answer as there must be a way to do it through non ggplot channes

Comment: I had the same problem with plotly in python and came across this question. As I don't know R, I don't know if the same would work here, so I can't give an answer but maybe the following would still help: In plotly for python, there is a `spanmode`:
```
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(y=distances, name=name, spanmode="hard"))
```
From the documentation, I would think that this works in R as well: https://plotly.com/r/reference/#violin-spanmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way to fix the behaviour of plotly (probably worth making a bug report for this).  A workaround would be to filter your data to only draw violin plots on  groups whose range is greater than zero.  If you also need to show where the other groups are, you can use a boxplot for these.

To demonstrate, I use `library(data.table)` for the filtering stage.  You could use dplyr or base versions of the same procedure if you prefer:

```
setDT(df)[, toplot := diff(range(val)) > 0, group]
```

Now we can plot the groups using different trace styles depending on whether they should have violins or not

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = df[(toplot)], x = ~group, y = ~val, split = ~group, 
            type = 'violin', box = list(visible = F), points = F) %>% 
  add_boxplot(data = df[(!toplot)], x = ~group, y = ~val, split = ~group)
```

[image]